How to run a function multiple times with different return values?
I have a test that intermittently fails during automated builds so I want to add some retries to my tool. However, I'm not sure how to force the tool to fail and verify that it has retried before I get the usual satisfactory outcome.
The program I am testing is written in Python, but some functionality is provided by the Whitebox Tools Rust library, via a Python wrapper.
The function that calls Whitebox Tools looks like this:
def run_wbt(func, *args, err_type=None, err_msg=None, **kwargs):
    path_args = [args[1]] if isinstance(args[1], str) else args[1]
    default_err = f"An error has occurred with the {func.__name__} Whitebox tool."
    for retry in range(3):
        rc = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if rc == 0:
            break

    if rc != 0 or not all(os.path.exists(path) for path in path_args):
        if err_type:
            raise err_type(err_msg or default_err)

        raise DatasetError(default_err)

You call it by passing in a Whitebox function and other parameters. We do this at least 5 times during a normal run of the tool. For example:
        run_wbt(
            wbt.breach_depressions_least_cost,
            dem_in_path,
            dem_fix_path,
            dist=dist,
            max_cost=max_cost,
            min_dist=min_dist,
            fill=fill,
        )

As the Whitebox tools function I am calling is third-party, I can't make any changes to it. It just absorbs any errors and just returns an exit code.
What I have tried to do is to use the pytest-mock mocker fixture to replace the return code with two bad codes followed by one good.
    # TODO actually run the function on the 3rd attempt
    mock_bdlc = mocker.MagicMock(
        spec=WhiteboxTools.breach_depressions_least_cost, side_effect=[1, 1, 0]
    )
    mocker.patch("whitebox.WhiteboxTools.breach_depressions_least_cost", mock_bdlc)

This does give me the exit codes I want, but I still need the Whitebox tool to run, to produce the outputs I am expecting. There are other Whitebox calls after this one and they need the outputs of this function. It's ok if the function actually runs on each retry, it will just overwrite the outputs on the second and third runs.
All I've managed to do so far is either mock the function and return different exit codes or just run the original function. I can't figure out how to do both.

Are you trying to mock that, or test it? Where's the retrying happening? Where's the test?

I'm trying to test myfunc, but the problem is that it occasionally fails (we don't know why, race condition maybe). So I've added a retry to the function and I want to test that the retry works.

"I need the whitebox tool to run, to produce the outputs I am expecting" - do you? If you're testing the wrapper's retry logic (not actually shown anywhere), then surely all it gets back is the 0? In that context side_effect=[1, 1, 0] seems fine - you'd also potentially have return_value=1 to test the retry hitting a limit. In a test you generally want either the real thing (you're testing it) or a test double (you're testing something that uses it), not both.

Ok, I've rewritten the question and provided more example code which hopefully explains what I'm trying to do. I'm really trying to keep it simple and not post hundreds of lines here, but it's a fairly simple question. I want to run a function more than once and return a different exit code each time. That's all.

"I want to run a function more than once and return a different exit code each time" - fundamentally, that's where this is not fitting together. If you're testing a consumer of that function, then a test double with a side effect does return a different exit code each time. If you're unit testing run_wbt, you don't even need to patch anything; you can just pass a mock with an appropriate side effect as func. If you're doing integration testing, then you already have the retry logic and can run the real implementation to generate whatever the real outputs are.

But I want to run wbt.breach_depressions_least_cost more than once, the function I'm passing in to run_wbt. I'm not sure where you think the retry logic is on the integration test. I don't want to rerun the whole test, just one function that is called somewhere in the middle of it.

And it will do that, until func returns non-zero or has been tried 3 times. You can verify (at a unit level) that run_wbt does that just fine against a test double with a side effect. And when you test the real implementation (at the integration level) then you know all of those five functions individually will be retried as needed until they do generate their real outputs. You have to think about what you're actually testing - there's no requirement here (and it rarely if ever makes sense) to both mock and not mock the same thing for the same test.

Or if you're testing the thing that orchestrates those five calls with a low-level test, you can patch out run_wbt entirely and just assert that it's called with the right things from wbt and the corresponding other parameters, having testing elsewhere to verify that that function will then retry any or all of those as needed. Basically if you run the real function it's going to return what it's going to return - you only control that when you replace it with a test double to test its collaborators.

I realise this is not ideal, but I don't want to commit anything until I'm sure it works. Normally, I use the tests to do that. As it is, I'm going to give up on testing this and just wait until the CI fails again (or hopefully not now I have a retry in there!).

I figured it out - the retry and the successful output need to be two separate stages of the test. I can use the patch stop method to turn off the mock then the test will run normally.
In this example, self._test_task is part of our test harness. I've set the maximum number of retries to 3, so the tool will fail while the mock is still handing out bad exit codes.
    def test_d8_pointer_inputs__burn_streams_shp(self, mocker):
        args = []  # insert tool args here

        # 1. Fail and retry
        mock_bdlc = mocker.MagicMock(
            spec=WhiteboxTools.breach_depressions_least_cost, side_effect=[1, 2, 3, 4]
        )
        mock_bdlc.__name__ = "mocked bdlc"
        mocker.patch("whitebox.WhiteboxTools.breach_depressions_least_cost", mock_bdlc)
        expected = "An error has occurred with the mocked bdlc Whitebox tool"
        with self.assertLogs(level=logging.INFO) as log:
            self._test_task("d8_pointer", expected, args, compare_type=EXCEPTION)
        assert "Whitebox tool gave exit code 3 on attempt 3" in " ".join(log.output)
        mocker.stop(mock_bdlc)

        # 2. Run and compare DEM output
        expected = os.path.join(self.base_dir, "burn_streams", "fixed_dem_streams.tif")
        self._test_task("d8_pointer", expected, args, compare_type=RASTER)



Try writing your whole code using exceptions. So you would write
def_main():
    while False:
        try:
            "code"
            return True
        except ValueError, TypeError, etc.:
            return False
        


I've added more information to my question - I'm running a third party function which I can't make changes to.
